# Accessing a subnet

Tags: networking, routing, subnet

I've a network configured in this way

```
ROUTER 1 (PUBLIC IP - PC1) ----> ROUTER 2 ----> PC2 (LOCAL IP)
```

I can locally access PC1 (192.168.1.2) from PC2 (10.0.0.2), but cannot do the opposite:

I'd like to be able to access PC2 from PC1.

I'm not such network expert.

Any advice, guide, tutorial to follow?

Comment: any routing table to show?

Answer (score 3):

The likely cause is that router 2's NAT is preventing any unsolicited traffic from passing through it.

You will have to go into Router 2's configuration interface and forward ports to PC 2.  You may need to also set up a DHCP reservation for PC 2 to give it a fixed IP for this.

Comment: unfourtunately, most consumer/soho class routers will not let you disable the nat or firewall, so the only option is to forward all the ports to services on PC2 that you want to expose to pc1. this however is an ugly option, since you can't do the same if you add PC3 to Router2's network.

Comment: can you explain me how do I forward all ports from pc1 to pc2? I can't figure it out

Comment: Unique for each router.  You'll need to read any manual that came with it.